# R, convert large dataset into JSON

Tags: json, r, large-files

I am trying to convert a large dataset into `JSON` but it is giving me errors because the dataset is too large. What I tried:

```
1. merged_final_json <- toJSON(merged_final, pretty = TRUE)
```

It is giving me an error:

> Error in paste(dQuote(names(x)), els, sep = ": ", collapse = sprintf(",%s",  : 
>     result would exceed 2^31-1 bytes

```
2. merged_final_json <- jsonlite::toJSON(merged_final, simplifyVector=FALSE)
```

> Error in collapse(tmp, inner = FALSE, indent = indent) : 
>     R character strings are limited to 2^31-1 bytes

What else could I try?

Comment: what do you want to do with merged_final_json next? would writing rows in batches to a json file help with your ultimate problem?